# What does "as good a film as the Coen brothers...have ever made" mean?

Tags: meaning, grammar, colloquialisms

What does "as good a film as the Coen brothers...have ever made" mean?  Does it mean  that the film is their best? what is the underlying structure?

Comment: @Janus: As it happens, the context of OP's example is [***No Country for Old Men** is as good a film as...*](http://www.rogerebert.com/reviews/no-country-for-old-men-2007). But unless I'm much mistaken, your "original" answer doesn't explain why it would be incorrect to have ***Psycho*** there (because that's not a Coen movie), whereas that would be okay if it were *as good a film as **any** the Coens have ever made*. And to my ear at least, there's nothing wrong with including that ***any***, regardless of whether we're talking about the Coens' *NCFOM* or Hitchcock's *Psycho*.

Answer (score 4):

Saying it's as good a film as they've ever made doesn't mean it's necessarily their best, only that it's among their best films.

Answer (score 1):

The underlying structure of the sentence is as follows:

> - The Coen brothers have made many films.
> - Some of them have been great, some not so great.
> - Among the great ones [you could insert here, say, "Raising Arizona"] has to be one.

Comment: I agree that “Raising Arizona” is a good example, although Roger Ebert instead used “Fargo” for [a comparison](http://www.rogerebert.com/reviews/no-country-for-old-men-2007): «“No Country for Old Men” is as good a film as the Coen brothers, Joel and Ethan, have ever made, and they made “Fargo.”»