# Difference between "not as...as" and "not ...er than"

Tags: grammar, word-usage

In what kind of situation can we use "not as...as" not "not ...er than"?

> This question is not as easy as that one.
>   This question is not easier than that one.
>   This question is more difficult than that one.

I feel these three sentences indicate the same concept. How can we distinguish how to use these three sentences?

Comment: The second example could mean that the questions are equal in difficulty.

Comment: I've fixed your formatting.  This site uses markdown which results in some oddities in format.  Take a look at how I did it by hitting edit.  The way to force a line break is to hit enter and double space after it on the same line.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest difference is this:

> Question 1 is not as easy as question 2.

This means question 2 is easy, question 1 is harder.

> Question 1 is not easier than question 2.

Question 1 may be as hard as question 2, or it may be harder.

So in the case that question 1 is certainly harder than question two, both phrases are correct. But in the case that both questions could also have the same difficulty, only sentence 2 applies.

More importantly, there is also a different implication about the difficulty of the questions:

> Question 1 is not as easy as question 2.

Someone may think that question 2 is too easy, and suspect the other questions are easy too. You then tell them that question 1 is in fact not as easy as 2.

> Question 1 is not easier than question 2.

Here, someone probably thinks that question 1 is too easy, but your reassure them that the question is certainly not easier than question 2.

Answer (score 2):

These three sentences mix Negation into the Comparative and Equative constructions -- shaken, not stirred. This is quite a big load of semantics and syntax; do not operate heavy machinery.

This cocktail, and related delights, can be investigated further [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/121828/15299), as well as [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/120426/15299), and [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/118055/15299).
Chin, chin.