# much more a lot with adjective

Tags: adjectives

Are these correct?

- **much more + adjective** (I was much more busy);
- **a lot more + adjective** (I was a lot more busy);
- **much less + adjective** (I was much less busy);
- **a lot less + adjective** (I was a lot less busy);
- **a little + adjective;**
- **much/ a lot + adjective;**
- **a little more/less + adjective;**

What is right? Which may be similar?

Comment: _More_ and _much more_ are only used in [comparative constructions](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/118055/15299). They require more pieces than you have presented. There are some sentences where these words could fit together, but there are no complete comparative sentences here. Who were you much less busy than, for instance?

Comment: All of those sentences are fine. (I am assuming that they relate to previously written sentences, so that a comparison can be made.)

Answer (score 1):

"More busy" could almost always be phrased more concisely as "busier." There are few cases in which "more busy" is preferable to the comparative adjective "busier."

One such case is when "more busy" is comparative and positioned against another adjective in the sentence: "I was more busy than [adjective]." For a more specific example, "I was more busy than free" or "I was more busy than not."

"More busy" may also be acceptable when used as a rhetorical or oratorical device. For example, this quote by Dag Hammerskjöld: ["The more we do, the more we can do; the more busy we are, the more leisure we have,"](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Dag_Hammarskj%C3%B6ld) uses "more busy" to create parallelism.

"Less busy" does not have an equivalent word the way "more busy" does. Therefore, "less busy" is correct, as long as it is followed by "than." E.g., "less busy than..." You could also use "not as busy as [noun]" to convey a similar meaning.

In short, I'd recommend rephrasing to say "busier" anytime you find yourself using the phrase "more busy." It's rarely incorrect, and will make your writing more concise.